# Android: Webview does not display content until I touch on it

Tags: android, webview

I have created 4 `webviews` in an item of `listview` and 40 items in `listview`
when my webview loaded, sometimes `webview` does not show content. I need to touch on it or swipe on it to show content. Sometimes it works perfectly.

**Here is my video describes my problem:
https://youtu.be/YnVxGXEvsq0**

I have already tried:

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

and added this `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in manifest
and

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

but not working.

I dont know, I think my problem is because of too much `webviews` but I use `javascript` in `webview` to display my content so I can not change it to `TextView`.

```
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
w.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
            + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
            + "showMathMenu: false, "
            + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
            + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], "
            + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
            + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "

            + "'HTML-CSS': {"
            + "styles: {'.MathJax': {color: '#00AAFF'}}}"
            + "});</script>"
            + "<script type='text/javascript' "
            + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
            + "></script>"
            + "<script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {"
            + "math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
            // below, toMathML() rerurns literal MathML string
            + "mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;"
            + "}; getEscapedMML = function() {"
            + "math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
            // below, toMathMLquote() applies &-escaping to MathML string input
            + "mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}"
            + "</script>"
            + "<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    }
```

});

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try using shouldOverrideUrlLoading in your code

`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});`

it may help.

Comment: This is my video to describes my problem : https://youtu.be/YnVxGXEvsq0. Can you help me, please?

Comment: use this method to format your url '     URIUtil.encodeQuery("url...");    ' to overcome the problem due to URI parsing and loadurl in shouldOverrideUrlLoading@Adam